# I can't play any audio using Python on MacOS M1 Macbook

Tags: python, macos, audio

I am using python to generate a signal sweep (MLS) and measuring the impulse response of a room. I have the code running successfully and can plot the impulse response. My problem is actually hearing the audio. I run the code, hear nothing, and the plot is flat because no audio is being emitted or recorded. At the moment I am using my M1 Macbook pro with no external audio device connected.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sounddevice as sd

def generate_mls(length):
    # Generate Maximum Length Sequence (MLS)
    n = int(np.log2(length)) - 1
    sequence = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(2 ** n) - 1)
    mls = np.array(sequence.tolist() * int(length / (2 ** n - 1)), dtype=np.float32)
    mls -= 0.5
    mls *= 2
    return mls

def play_and_capture(mls, sample_rate):
    print("Playing MLS...")
    sd.play(mls, samplerate=sample_rate, blocking=True)
    print("Recording...")
    recording = sd.rec(len(mls), samplerate=sample_rate, channels=1, dtype='float64')
    sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished
    print("Recording finished.")
    return recording.flatten()

def plot_impulse_response(impulse_response, sample_rate):
    time = np.arange(len(impulse_response)) / sample_rate
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    plt.plot(time, impulse_response)
    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
    plt.title('Room Impulse Response')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

# Define parameters
length = 2**15  # Length of MLS signal
sample_rate = 44100  # Hz

# Generate MLS
mls = generate_mls(length)

# Play MLS and capture the response
impulse_response = play_and_capture(mls, sample_rate)

# Plot the impulse response
plot_impulse_response(impulse_response, sample_rate)
```

Comment: For reference, Macbook pro M2 working fine. Had to run twice as the first run asked for microphone permission. Second run was fine. This will just be the a system response. You would still need to use an [impulse estimation algorithm](https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/impzest.html)

Comment: so... you can't play audio? not a recording issue, not a DSP issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the code in a virtual environment, when running on a local machine in a terminal window, I was able to successfully run the code and hear/record audio.